# add get and set to the prototype chain of a constructor

Tags: javascript, get, set

This piece of code supposed to do a simple task which is to calculate the distance between two points.Actually i wrote this code to learn how get and set works as i am new to this concept.But it constantly giving me errors like unexpected comma/semi-colon is there.I could not find out what the actual problem is.

Also i have a question if i want to set new values for x and y variables,how can i acheive this??I mean can i treat the set property as a function and send values simply points.addition(5,6,7,8) ?

```
   (function(){
   function Point(x1,x2,y1,y2){
      this.x1=x1;
      this.x2=x2;
      this.y1=y1;
      this.y2=y2;
   }
   Point.prototype={
      get addition(){
          return Math.sqrt((this.x2-this.x1)+(this.y2-this.y1));
      },
      set addition(x1,x2,y1,y2){
           this.x1=x1;
           this.x2=x2;
           this.y1=y1;
           this.y2=y2;
      }
   };
   var points=new Point(1,2,3,4);
   console.log(points.addition);
   })();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the good way to declare setter and getter. See [the mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters).

Here a live sample with fixes:

```js
(function(){
   function Point(x1,x2,y1,y2){
      this.x1=x1;
      this.x2=x2;
      this.y1=y1;
      this.y2=y2;
   }
   Object.defineProperty(Point.prototype, "addition", {
      get: function () {
          return Math.sqrt((this.x2-this.x1)+(this.y2-this.y1));
      },
      set: function (point) {
           this.x1 = point.x1;
           this.x2 = point.x2;
           this.y1 = point.y1;
           this.y2 = point.y2;
      }
   });
   var points = new Point(1,2,3,4);
   console.log(points.addition);
   document.getElementById("output").textContent = points.addition;
})();
```

```html
<div id="output"/>
```

Comment: thanks!!you said this is not a good way..but this isn't the wrong way.Then why my code didn't work??

Comment: Maybe you use an Obsolete syntaxes: `In the past, JavaScript supported several other syntaxes for defining getters and setters. None of these syntaxes were supported by other engines, and support has been removed in recent versions of JavaScript. See this dissection of the removed syntaxes for further details on what was removed and how to adapt to those removals.`